# import database dump to mysql using visual foxpro

Tags: mysql, visual-foxpro

I used leaves stru2mysql.prg and vfp2mysql_upload.prg to create a .sql dump file from DBF's. I connect to mysql database from vfp using ODBC.I KNOW how upload the sql dump file but i need to automate the whole process i.e after creating the dump file,my visual foxpro program can upload the dump file without a third party(automatically). I thought of using the source command but that needs to be run in mysql prompt.The assumption here is that my end users dont know how to import(which most of them dont).Please advice on how i can automate importation of sql file to mysql database.thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are the various SQL* functions in Foxpro. See the VFP help or MSDN on `SQLCONNECT` (or `SQLSTRINGCONNECT`), `SQLEXEC`, and `SQLDISCONNECT` functions to get you started. Microsoft provided good examples on each in the documentation.

You may also want to use `FILETOSTR` to get the output from Leafe's programs into a string for the `SQLEXEC` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps I use to take data from a Visual FoxPro Database and upload to a MySql Database. These are all put into a custom method on a form, which is fired by a command button.  For example the method would be 'uploadnewdata' and I pass parameters for whichever data tables I need

1) Connect to the Server - I use MySql ODBC
2) Validate the user (this uses a SQLEXEC to pull the correct matching record for a users tables
    IF M.WorkingDatabase<>-1
nRetVal=SQLEXEC(m.WorkingDatabase,"SELECT * FROM users", "csrUsersOnServer")

```
SELECT csrUsersOnServer
SELECT userid,FROM csrUsersOnServer;
WHERE ALLTRIM(UPPER(userid))=ALLTRIM(UPPER(lcRanchUser));
 AND ALLTRIM(UPPER(lcPassWord))=ALLTRIM(UPPER(lchPassWord));
INTO CURSOR ValidUsers
IF _TALLY>=1
     ELSE
=MESSAGEBOX("Your Premise ID Does Not Match Any Records On The Server","System Message")
RETURN 0
ENDIF
ELSE
=MESSAGEBOX("Unable To Connect To Your Database", "System Message")
RETURN 0
ENDIF
```

3) Once that is successful I create my base cursor (this is the one I'm sending from)
4) I then loop through that cursor creating variable for the values in the fields
5) then using the SQLEXEC, and INSERT INTO, I update each record
6) once the program is finished processing the cursor, it generates a messagebox with the 'finished' message and control returns to the form.

All the user has to do, is select the starting table and enter their login information